# In-App Billing Testing without Uploading apk

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-testing

I am new to android development. I have to implement In-App Billing in this purpose i have downloaded the source code from multiple tutorial sites (like Blundell) and implemented one tutorial by my-self from this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html).

I want to test this application without uploading APK to the developer console. I have tried no. of searches on Google and saw links on StackOverflow but nothing helps about this.  For product ID I used `android.test.purchased`.

Any guidance or steps and prerequisites to test In-app without uploading to Developer Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found solution to my problem. May be this could have been happened to most of people. Just log in with **Gmail account** on to the target device, in my case it is nexus 7. For In-App Billing for testing purpose or purchasing real product from Google Play you have to log in with the google account to purchase or test.

Answer (score 2):

You cant test this without uploading it to the developer console, 
But to upload it to the developer console does not mean that you need to release it, the app can be in the developer console under unpublished and then you can test it.
Dont forget to add you mail as a tester so you dont need to pay while testing.

Comment: you forgot to mention how i can test without uploading it? because in present scenario i have to test it without uploading. Thanks for quick reply please tell me how i can test it without uploading it using product id **android.test.purchased**.

Comment: In order to test the in app function you need to upload the apk. I do not think it is possible to test it without uploading it.
However when you uploaded it once you don't need to upload a new apk eve rtime you going to try it.

Comment: It is possible to test the In-App Billing with reserved product id without uploading it to the developer console. But if you want to test it with your own product or in-app products then it is necessary to Upload the apk file to developer console.